# How can store my APP identity on specific iOS device?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode6

How can I keep installation track of my app on particular iOS device? Actually I want to check that my app was installed on a device or its first time installation. I tried identifierForVendor but it got change on every install.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

Easiest would be to implement [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

If you have your own reporting, you could use a 3rd part library to identify the device its on and then send that info to you... such as:

https://github.com/QuickBlox/SuperSample-ios/tree/master/Classes/Helpers/DeviceHardware

Comment: I have to upload app to AppStore. Where your solution is for jailbroken devices.

Comment: Where does my solution require a jail broken device? I am using this in a production app with no issues.

Comment: which solution you are using QuickBlox?

Comment: @AhadKhan Why do either of the solutions provided require a Jailbroken device? `Google Analytics` is a well known solution used by a hell of a lot of developers to track app usage and is perfectly acceptable by Apple (though not sure it is the best for your solution). And all that `QuickBlox` is, is a class that someone has made no different from you writing a new class. So please can you detail where a Jailbroken device would be required?